# The API call doesn't append properly in NextJS

Tags: next.js

Folder structure
-Pages
--Support
---StaffTable.js

```
await axios.post('api/updateStaffDetails', { data: dataToSubmit });
```

What I try: I once encountered this issue this is my previous solution, I just add '/' infront of the API call but this time it doesn't work

```
await axios.post('/api/updateStaffDetails', { data: dataToSubmit });
```

My thoughts: It seems like nextJS 'glued' the first name of the page into any API call made in that page in this case a nested static route /support/StaffTable the first name is support.

```
Actual: /localhost/support/updateUser
```

```
Expected: /localhost/api/updateUser
```

Much help or guide or is much much much appreciated . Thank you , have a good day

Comment: Are you making the request server or client side?

Comment: I'm taking the request from client side

Comment: What's your `/pages/api` folder structure? Also, can you share the full code where the axios request is being made?

Answer (score 0):

This should work -

```
await axios.post('/api/updateStaffDetails', { data: dataToSubmit });
```

Any file inside the folder `pages/api` is mapped to `/api/*` and will be treated as an API endpoint instead of a page. So axois request to `'/api/updateStaffDetails'` will call the handler(export a function as default) written in `pages/api/updateStaffDetails.js`